# How do I eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation?

Tags: parametric, curves

Given the two parametric equations

$$x=t^2+1$$

$$y=t+1 \iff t= y-1$$

How do I eliminate parameter $t$ to find a Cartesian equation?  Do I substitute?

This is confusing me, so I would appreciate it if somebody could explain how to do this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can get $t$ from $s$ also. Then eliminate $t$ from the two relations.

Answer (score 2):

Both $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$.

Solving $y = t+1$ to obtain $t$ as a function of $y$: we have $t = y-1.\quad$

So given $x=t^2 + 1$, by substitution of $t = (y-1)$, we have $$x=(y-1)^2 +1 \iff x-1=(y-1)^2$$

We have a horizontal parabola with vertex at $(1, 1)$ and opening to the right (positive direction.)